# Setting default perspective in config.ini (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, config

If I want to set the default perspective in config.ini to be Resource or Java, what do I have to type in exactly to achieve this. I've tried a few things but haven't had any luck yet. Currently, it always opens in Java, but I want to be able to set a default perspective that is applied for any new workspace that is created, e.g. so it defaults to Resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default perspective id in the `plugin_customization.ini` file with:

```
org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=perspective id
```

Comment: This appears to be working as I want, so that it sets the default for all newly created workspaces. I have located two plugin_customization.ini files within the eclipse root folder however. Also, do you have a list of perspective id's?

Comment: The correct plugin_customization.ini depends on exactly what Eclipse 'product' you are running. For example for my setup using the 'Eclipse SDK' download it is the one on the 'org.eclipse.sdk' plugin but I think it will be different for the larger packaged downloads.

Answer (score 2):

No need to configure in the ini file. You can set the default perspective by going to:

```
Window > Preferences > General > Perspectives
```

Now choose one and click **Make Default**.
For more information, read the user guide, [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?nav=%2F0). Information on perspectives can be found under **Tasks** and **Working with perspectives**.

If you want to set for all workspaces, you add the following to the `plugin_customization.ini`:

```
org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=some ID
```

@Greg-449 answered this before me below.

Comment: No this sets it for a single workspace - I want to set it for all workspaces!

Comment: Is there a list of the different ID's I can choose, e.g. I know of: org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective and org.eclipse.ui/defaultPerspectiveId=org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective